# SQL Server Reporting Services 3.0 - default sort by count

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

Creating dashboard of list of computers with ad - sccm details.  In reporting services 3.0 I have a table like this from a much bigger data set.

```
OSName1           | OSName2           | OSName3
(count computers) | (count computers) | (count computers)
```

I am trying to sort this group by the count.

```
Group Properties -> Sorting -> Add 
Sort by =SUM(Fields!AD_CN.Value)
```

I always get aggregate sort error.  Anyone know how I can sort this table by the counts in the group properties?  Can't sort in advance, because the dataset contains a lot of data about the computers.  This leaves me with sorting on each report.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!!

Comment: You shouldn't need the `sum`

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is define the scope of your aggregate. The format will look like this:

```
=SUM(Fields!AD_CN.Value, "YourGroupName")
```

Make sure you use the name of the group that you want the counts to be sorted by. You can see the groups at the bottom section of the window. It is helpful to rename them so that they are easy to identify. It's also best to name them before you write the expression, because the expressions don't update if you rename them later on.